# How to copy the all Wordpress media items to another custom plugin folder?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, uploads, media-library

I created a custom plugin to compress/zip all media items in a folder for that I create a plugin and inside the plugin, I create a folder. Now on that folder, I want to add/copy my all WordPress project media items. And also when I upload any new items like (pdf, image, etc) so it also add on that custom folder

Please help me with how and what code I used to copy all media items to another custom folder inside the plugins folder.

Comment: You shouldn’t add anything to your Plugin’s folder. It will be erased when the plugin is updated.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying can you tell me how I add two paths for media upload, which means when I upload any file so it uploaded on default path as well as a custom folder path?